# vim null symbol effecting string ^@

Tags: python-3.x, vim

I am using the following function to get the Selected test

```
let s:drawscript = "somerandom.py"

func! GetSelectedText()
  normal gv"xy
  let result = getreg("x")
  normal gv
  return result
endfunc

vnoremap <tab><tab> :<c-u>call Box(GetSelectedText())<CR>
func! Box(text)
    let s:b = '"' . a:text . '"'
    echom s:b
    " exec boxcmd
    "echom 'hi'
    let c = ["python3", s:drawscript, s:b]
    execute ":.!".join(c, " ")
endfunc
```

I am trying to pass in the text selected to my python file, it works when I only select 1 line, but when I select multiple lines, there are "^@" symbols in the selected text which caused automatic execution which leads to an error. I just wanna pass in the text I have selected into the .py file.

[image: text]

[image: error]

Comment: You will need to substitute any unwanted character with something more usable. See `:help substitute()`. Also, note that `:.!` operates on the whole current line. It seems like you are approaching your problem from a wrong angle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a matter of escaping special characters for the shell. While you correctly thought of quoting the text, you missed to escape the line separator. There's the function [`shellescape()`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#shellescape%28%29) which takes care of this and more, so you can replace

```
    let s:b = '"' . a:text . '"'
```

by

```
    let s:b = shellescape(a:text, 1)
```

Comment: thanks alot, not used to login on to stackoverflow